# Convert Output String into List - Python

Tags: python, list, append, output, text-files

I'm converting a file of human ORF codon codes into two lists, one of ORF_ID fragments and one of the actual sequence data.

```
for i in fasta_file:
    ID_list = []
    sequences = []
    if '>' in i:
        ORF_start = i.find('>')
        ORF_end = i.find('PERFECT_MATCH')
        ORF_ID = i[ORF_start:ORF_end+13]
        ID_list.append(ORF_ID)
        print type(ID_list)
    else:
        sequences.append(i)
```

When I print the lists, both are not a list of strings, but many lines of tiny lists.

Example:

```
What I want = separate list of ORF_ID and another data or ['a','b','c']
What I get (represented through variables) = 
['a']
[]
['b']
[]
['c']
```

This always happens to me on python. I would love some help.

Comment: should you not be creating sequences and ID_list outside the loop?

Comment: biopython probably does already what you are trying to do ....

Answer (score 0):

you are resetting the lists inside the for loop.

See if this gives you what you are after:

```
ID_list = []
sequences = []
for i in fasta_file:
    ORF_start = i.find('>')
    if ORF_start >= 0:
        ORF_end = i.find('PERFECT_MATCH', ORF_start)
        ORF_ID = i[ORF_start:ORF_end+13]
        ID_list.append(ORF_ID)
    else:
        sequences.append(i)
print ID_list
print sequences
```

if `fasta_file` is

```
['gattaca >cippalippaPERFECT_MATCHxyz', 'sgnoppa >cippalippaPERFECT_MATCHxyz', 'wslewa >cippalippaPERFECT_MATCHxyz', 'whatever', 'anotherone']
```

it produces this output:

```
['>cippalippaPERFECT_MATCH', '>cippalippaPERFECT_MATCH', '>cippalippaPERFECT_MATCH']
['whatever', 'anotherone']
```